# I need a formula that will automatically fill in the value 'closed' for each blank cell in a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I need a formula that will automatically fill in the value 'closed' for each blank cell in a single column.

This formula should not edit any cell that already has a value in there.

[image]

Comment: Use `BYROW()` function or need `VBA` macro.

Comment: would =BYROW(closed) be correct?

Comment: Post few sample data so that we can suggest function.

Comment: You will need to develop a VBA solution.  Or have the results in another column

Comment: @Young.Aborsh `=BYROW(A2:A16,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","Closed",x)))`. Remember function can't change value in cells. Only appear result.

Comment: This did not work. The column I have selected does already have a formula in there including the blank cells

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a formula, you need a pretty Excel-trick:

1. Select all cells in the mentioned column.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, "Special", "Blanks":

[image]

3. Press "Ok"
4. Click in the formula bar and type "Closed"
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd> (not simply "ENTER")
6. Look amazed :-)

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. I don't know if it's because it's in a pivot table?

Comment: @Young.Aborsh: can you edit your question, showing a screenshot of your table?

Comment: unfortunately, my reps not high enough to add images to questions just yet.

Comment: I've upvoted your question, what about now?

Comment: Thanks, see picture. there are 6189 rows on the table. and I am referring to column F.

Comment: How did you select all cells in column "F"? In the name box (top left), you can put something like `F2:F6189`.

Comment: Yes I've done this and it's highlighted the column F in the table

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question by simply using the 'replace' tool for under 'Find & Select' option. see screenshot. [image]